# Trying to import the flask Admin module in pycharm

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.admin import Admin



app = Flask(__name__)

admin = Admin(app)
# Add administrative views here

app.run(debug=True)
```

using python 3.3

getting error: "ImportError: No module named 'flask_admin'" when

I have already set up an interpreter and downloaded the latest flask & flask_admin

I am new to pycharm and python in general so I'm sure it is something stupid I am doing wrong.

Comment: Flask-Admin is separate from Flask. Did you install Flask-Admin as well?

Answer (score 2):

figured it out, was running from command line and it was using the default interpreter and not my custom one

Comment: really weird--same with me. Thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 0):

Check if project developed using makefile

if makefile is there just follow readme.md

```
make install
make run
```

Otherwise bellow steps

First Create Virtual ENV:

```
virtualenv env
```

Put Project Inside env:

```
anywhere parallel to bin,lib,etc
```

Then Activate env:

```
 source venv/bin/activate
```

When you inside env run bellow command :

```
 pip install -r requirements/development.txt 
(use correct file path according your project structure)
```

For Python 3:

```
$python3

import flask_admin

quit()
```

For Python 2:

```
$python

import flask_admin

quit()
```